# AS2 hide object from an array

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

A question about actionscript 2. 
I have two arrays - one for buttons, and the other one for movie clips that are triggered by the buttons:

```
var def:Array = [mc1, mc2, mc3];
var defBtn:Array = [btn1, btn2, btn3];
```

So I got the movie clips triggered by the respective buttons - any called movie clip is visible and plays its timeline.

```
for(i=0; i<def.length; i++) {
    defBtn[i].iv = i;
    def[i].iv = i;
    defBtn[i].onRelease = function() {
        for( i=0; i<defBtn.length; i++ ) { 
            def[this.iv]._visible = true;
            def[this.iv].play();
        } 
    };          
};
```

However any called movie clip stays visible all the time.
I want all movie clips from the array to be invisible except the one called by respective button.

Have no idea how to do this because I NEED to use onRelease (not onRollOut) to make the movie clips dissappear after they animate for a little bit.

I would appreciate help with this AS code please!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been many years since I've had to write AS2 code, but I'll give it a try...

On each button, set the following code, changing the index value to be respective to the button's index in the array:

```
on(release){
    showClip(0);  // change value here as needed
}
```

On the same timeline the buttons and movieclips exist, you'll need this code:

```
var def:Array = [mc1, mc2, mc3];
var defBtn:Array = [btn1, btn2, btn3];

function showClip(clipToShow:Number) {

    // hide all clips
    for( i = 0; i < def.length; i++ ) {
        def[i]._visible = false;
        def[i].stop();
    }

    // only show clip after all clips have been hidden
    def[clipToShow]._visible = false;
    def[clipToShow].stop();

};
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a way to compile AS2 code on my machine because I have Adobe CC 2015, which no longer supports AS2; otherwise, I would have tested this code for you. Hope this works for you though. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: Hi Anil,
Many thanks for answering my question. And respect for writing a code in AS2 even though you haven't been using it for a long time!
However it does not work, all movie clips ddissappear including the one called by a clicked button.

I am very bad with AS3 but I can give it a try. Is there a change you could give me a script in AS3 that would do the job I wanted to do with the above AS2 code?

All other actions I have in my fla are pretty simple so I can translate them to AS3 by myself (at least I hope!! :))

So many thanks!

Comment: Update - your code is working like a charm! 
Sorry about confusion - my mistake!
THANK YOU!!!!